# How do I get a null response from a $resource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-resource

How do I get a null response from a $resource?

I am running this:

```
angular.module("services").factory('Member', function($resource) {
  var Member = $resource('/api/v1/member.json');

  Member.current = Member.get();

  return Member;
});
```

But the server is responding with:

```
null
```

Because the user is not logged in.

But when I log the result I get this:

```
Resource
  0: "n"
  1: "u"
  2: "l"
  3: "l"
  $promise: Object
  $resolved: true
  __proto__: Resource
```

Where as I would have expected literally `null`.

Comment: why do these good unasked questions get so little attention these days? Btw @stewie answered the question on the point (y)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`$resource.get` method, by default, expects the JSON response to be an object (when parsed).
When calling `$resource.get()`, the result is going to be an instance of the $resource.

In your example, calling `Member.get({id:1})` will produce a $resource instance that is created by calling [`new Member()` <sup>source</sup>](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.8/src/ngResource/resource.js#L491) and then [populated <sup>source</sup>](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.8/src/ngResource/resource.js#L528) (when XHR is completed) with properties of the parsed JSON response:

```
shallowClearAndCopy(data, value);
```

The signature of the function with which your `Member` instance is populated is as follows:

```
function shallowClearAndCopy(src, dst) {
  dst = dst || {};

  angular.forEach(dst, function(value, key){
    delete dst[key];
  });

  for (var key in src) {
    if (src.hasOwnProperty(key) && key.charAt(0) !== '$' && key.charAt(1) !== '$') {
      dst[key] = src[key];
    }
  }

  return dst;
}
```

Glancing the function body you will realise that the function does not expect `src` parameter to be anything else but object (`for (var key in src) { ...`). So, if you provide it with string `"null"` the result will be:

```
{1: "n", 2: "u", 3: "l", ...}
```

---

ngResource is built to support a RESTfull API with JSON as an implied data transfer format, hence you won't be able to use responses such as `"null"` or anything else which isn't a valid JSON.

---

**Unless.**

Unless you make use of [`transformResponse`](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/docs/api/ngResource.%24resource) to convert `"null"` to something like `{'null': true}` on the fly:

```
app.factory('Member', function($resource) {
  var Member = $resource('member.txt', {}, {
    get: {
      method: 'GET',
      isArray: false,
      transformResponse: function(data, headersGetter){
        if(data === 'null'){
          return {null: true};
        }
        return angular.fromJson(data);
      }
    }
  });
  return Member;
});

$scope.member = Member.get({id: 1});
console.log($scope.member); // --> {null: true}
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/pIYUNJpXZYEH0HoDKl1h?p=preview)**

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine. But seeing this kind of output in the console is a pain in the -muted-. One wants to fix it right away, setting any options for result formats, changing urls, http/https // fiddling etc.

But the thing is

> Calling a URL which is not allowed, because the user is not logged in.

One expects a nice [**`403`**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3) so `$resource`s **fault handler** executes.

This way your result handler does not execute at all ;)

```
Member.current = Member.get; //note removed () here

// then outside call:
Member.current(
  function(result) {
    // should not execute for 403
  }, 
  function(fault) {
    // TODO: handle case: 'user not logged in'
  });
```